# Parsing Text file and placing contents into an Array Powershell

Tags: text-files, powershell-2.0

I am looking for a way to parse a text file and place the results into an array in powershell.

I know select-string -path -pattern will get all strings that match a pattern.  But what if I already have a structured textfile, perhaps pipe delimminated, with new entries on each line.  Like so:

prodServ1a
prodServ1b
prodServ1c

C:\dir\serverFile.txt

How can I place each of those servers into an array in powershell that I can loop through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say 'pipe delimited, like so' but your example isn't pipe delimited. I'll imagine it is, then you need to use the `Import-CSV` commandlet. e.g. if the data file contains this:

```
prodServ1a|4|abc
prodServ1b|5|def
prodServ1c|6|ghi
```

then this code:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path test.dat -Header "Product","Cost","SerialNo" -Delimiter "|"
```

will import and split it, and add headers:

```
$data

Product                    Cost                       SerialNo
-------                    ----                       --------
prodServ1a                 4                          abc
prodServ1b                 5                          def
prodServ1c                 6                          ghi
```

Then you can use

```
foreach ($item in $data) {
    $item.SerialNo
}
```

Comment: Edit: I missed the important -Delimiter bit that makes it work with the pipe character! Updated.

Comment: Quick question, is there a way to anonymously get the strings from item object?  I have tried $item[n] and $item.fieldn, while the latter didnt' through me an exception It still didn't work.  I am assuming if I add headers to the import command, that is what it is expecting?

Comment: @DmainEvent I do not know of a way, and cannot find one with quick looking. I recommend you post a new question and other people can see it too. (But as a side comment, you must have headers as the first line in the file, or using `Import-CSV -Header ...`, otherwise it will take the first line of the file as header names and you will miss that row of data).

Answer (score 1):

If your data is flat or unstructured, but has a pattern such as delimited by a space or comma and no carriage returns or line feeds, you can use the Split() method.

```
PS>$data = "prodServ1a prodServ1b prodServ1c"

PS>$data
prodServ1a prodServ1b prodServ1c

PS>$data.Split(" ")
prodServ1a
prodServ1b
prodServ1c
```

Works particularly well with someone sending you a list of IP addresses separated by a comma.