# Log Parsing via Powershell - print all array elements after nth element

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, logging

I'm parsing a log file that is space delimited for the first 7 elements and then a log message or sentence follows.  I know just enough to get around in PS, and I'm learning more each day, so I'm not sure this is the best way to do this and apologies if I'm not leveraging a more efficient means that would be second nature to you.  I'm using -split(' ')[n] to extract each field of the log file line by line.  I'm able to extract the first parts fine as they are space-delimited, but I'm not sure how to get the rest of the elements up to the end of the line.

```
$logFile=Get-Content $logFilePath
$dateStamp=$logfile -split(' ')[0]
$timeStamp=$logfile -split(' ')[1]
$requestID=$logfile -split(' ')[3]
$binaryID=$logfile -split(' ')[4]
$logID=$logfile -split(' ')[5]
$action=$logfile -split(' ')[6]

$logMessage=$logfile -split(' ')[?]
```

This is not a CSV that I can import.  I'm more familiar with string manipulation in bash so I am able to successfully replace spaces in the first 7 elements, and the end, with "," :

```
#!/bin/bash

inputFile="/cygdrive/c/Temp/logfile.log"
outputFile="/cygdrive/c/Temp/test_log.csv"

echo "\"DATE\",\"TIME\",\"HYPEN\",\"REQUESTID\",\"BINARY\",\"PROC_NUMBER\",\"MESSAGE\"" > $outputFile

while read -a line
do
        arrLength=$(echo ${#line[@]})
        echo \"${line[0]}\",\"${line[1]}\",\"${line[2]}\",\"${line[3]}\",\"${line[4]}\",\"${line[5]}\",\"${line[@]:6:$arrLength}\"
done < $inputFile >> $outputFile
```

Can you help either printing the array elements from position n to the end, or replacing the spaces appropriately in PS so I have a CSV that I can import?  Just trying to avoid the two-step process of converting it in bash, then importing it in PS but I'm still researching. I did find this post [Parsing Text file and placing contents into an Array Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764622/parsing-text-file-and-placing-contents-into-an-array-powershell)
for importing the file assuming it's space-delimited and that works for the first 7 elements but not sure about everything after that.

Of course I welcome any other PS solutions such as one of those [something]::SOMETHING things I've seen by googling that might do all this much more seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the maximum number of substrings in which the string is split like this:

```
$splittedRow = $logfile.split(' ',8)

$dateStamp=$splittedRow[0]
$timeStamp=$splittedRow[1]
$requestID=$splittedRow[3]
$binaryID=$splittedRow[4]
$logID=$splittedRow[5]
$action=$spltttedRow[6]

$logMessage=$splittedRow[7]
```

Comment: This works best for me at this point. As I parse I'm storing the result of each variable into a New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList and then exporting the results to CSV. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @deskFan. Im glad that my answer helped you! Can you please mark it as the best answer with the green check mark? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Viktor Be's answer:

```
$data = "111 22222 333 4444444 5 6 77 888888 9999999 0" #this is the content of file below for testing purposes
#$data = get-content -path C:\temp\mytest.txt

foreach ($line in $data){
    $splitted = $line.split(' ',8)
    $line_output= ""
    for ($i = 0;$i -lt 7;$i++){
        $line_output += "$($splitted[$i]);"
    }
    $line_output += $splitted[7]
    $line_output | out-file "C:\temp\MyCsvThatPowershellCanRead.csv" -append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to iterate over each line in the logfile and get the information you need the way you are doing. However, it's easy to grab the message field, which could include *`n`* number of spaces in the log message with a regular expression.

The following regex should work for you. Assuming `$line` is the current line you are on:

```
$line -match '(?<=(\S+\s+){6}).*'
$logMessage = $matches[0]
```

The way this expression works is that it looks for `.*` (which means any character 0 or more times) that comes after 6 occurences of non-whitespace characters followed by whitespace characters. The `.*` in this expression should match on your log message.